# How can I paste multiple line command with Docker interactive mode but not evaluating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb, pry

For example I am opening an interactive command line window.

```
docker exec -it container rails c
```

When I paste a multiple-line command, it evaluate every line instead of pasting a block. How can I configure it as not to evaluate?

```
Order.last
     .user
     .id
```

Comment: This is not really specific to docker, it's a common challenge with all ruby REPL instances (irb / pry / are-there-any-other?)

Answer (score 2):

Ah, simple trick here: type `begin` + enter, paste the code, type `end`:

```
begin
  Order.last
       .user
       .id
end
```

It cannot and should not be configurable. The reason is that the console cannot posisible know when you have finished typing the whole command, as the first line is a completely valid ruby statement. Things are slightly different if you adapt different coding style:

```
Order.last.
      user.
      id
```

The code above will work once copied to console (but gosh, I really hate that style!) because it is clear to the interpreter that the statement is not completed yet - similarly to missing closing bracket or quote. Wrapping the code in `begin`/`end` have the same effect - it tells the interpreter that the code is not yet completed, so it awaits for the final `end`.

Comment: Nice workaround. I can paste code block locally, which give me a sense its possible with Docker.